# PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] causes an old version of the site to appear at the bottom

Tags: database

I'm building a site in Drupal 7. It's still in development, and isn't "live" yet. While assing the Views Slideshow module, I suddenly got this error appearing at the bottom of the page. **Every** page, in fact, from then on:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at 
/var/www/drupal-7.7/includes/common.inc:2567) in drupal_send_headers() (line 1018 of 
/var/www/drupal-7.7/includes/bootstrap.inc).

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'access_exposed' doesn't have a 
default value: INSERT INTO {rules_config} (name, label, plugin, weight, status, module, 
data) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, 
:db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, 
:db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 
uc_payment_method_credit [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => Credit card conditions 
[:db_insert_placeholder_2] => and [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0 
[:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 2 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => uc_payment 
[:db_insert_placeholder_6] => O:8:"RulesAnd":12:
{s:9:"*parent";N;s:2:"id";N;s:12:"*elementId";N;s:6:"weight";i:0;s:8:"settings";a:0:
{}s:4:"name";s:24:"uc_payment_method_credit";s:6:"module";s:10:"uc_payment";s:6:"status";i:2;s
:5:"label";s:22:"Credit card conditions";s:11:"*children";a:0:{}s:7:"*info";a:1:
{s:9:"variables";a:1:{s:5:"order";a:2:
{s:4:"type";s:8:"uc_order";s:5:"label";s:5:"Order";}}}s:9:"*negate";b:0;} ) in 
drupal_write_record() (line 6861 of /var/www/drupal-7.7/includes/common.inc).
```

It looks like there's a problem with credit card things of some kind. I am using Ubercart for some of the website, but I didn't touch it at all. I'm not sure exactly when the error appeared, but it was towards the end of this tutorial: http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-install-views-slideshow-module-on-drupal7 And yet, I'm not certain that this has anything to do with it, considering it seems to have a problem with payments and cards and so forth.

This is the thing that confuses me the most: I copy-pasted and have been modifying another theme as an example to make my own, and no longer have the original php files inside my theme (though I have the unmodified theme itself in the `themes` folder, still). However, not only is the error causing a second copy of the site to appear at the bottom of my current one, it is also using the old `page.tpl.php` file (which no longer exists, as far as I can see, except in the original theme, itself), with the current modified `style.css`. Also, this still happens on the admin pages, which are using Garland (unmodified, so I can't see if it's using an old version or not).

Another recent change was to put the whole `web/sites/all` folder into svn, but I doubt that would affect anything.

I may be mixing cause and effect, here. It could be the site replication causing the payment error. How can I go about finding out/solving it?

Comment: You have way too many possible causes here.  First, make a backup.  Second, switch over to the default theme.  Clear the cache twice.  Does the problem reappear?  If yes, start disabling modules one by one (I would guess ubercart based on the output).  Clear the cache twice each time.  Does the problem disappear?  When you know which theme/module is causing the error(s), update your question.

Comment: Try running update.php. Looks like you updated rules.module but didn't run update.php.